# Datagrid is not enabling me to scroll between it's columns if I manually add the data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollbar, datagridtextcolumn

I'm creating a C# project where many columns of Combo Box are added programmatically in a datagrid.
Unfortunately when adding many columns, the datagrid is not able to display them all, and the horizontal scroll bar is disabled and unclickable..

Design :

```
<DataGrid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  x:Name="dg" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  Background="#FFDFF9F9" Height="76" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,82,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Code :

```
        foreach (var r in importMappings)
        {
            var dgtc = new DataGridTextColumn();
            dgtc.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", r.Key));
            var sp = new StackPanel();
            dgtc.Header = sp;
            sp.Children.Add(new Label { Content = r.Key });
            var combo = new ComboBox();
            sp.Children.Add(combo);
            combo.ItemsSource = excelHeaders;
            int x = combo.SelectedIndex;
            var selectedBinding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", r.Key));
            selectedBinding.Source = importMappings;
            combo.SetBinding(Selector.SelectedIndexProperty, selectedBinding);
            dgtc.CanUserSort = false;
            dgtc.CanUserReorder = false;
            dg.Columns.Add(dgtc);
        }
```

Live View :

[image]

The scroll bar is always disabled here.
Any ideas on how to make the scroll bar work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have any data row. After adding a row of data the scrollbar worked for me.

For testing just edit your datagrid to:

```
<DataGrid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  x:Name="dg" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  Background="#FFDFF9F9" Height="76" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,82,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<TextBlock />
</DataGrid>
```

The scrollbar should be working now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks fine now.
And by the way I used to program android apps not windows desktop.